# Custom 'ORDER BY' status in JIRA

Tags: jira, jql

Hi I have the following query for my filter:

```
project = BOARD AND status in (Backlog, New, Design, Dev, "Sign Off", Blocked) ORDER BY status ASC
```

I have my board and am stating what statuses it should display and I though it would display it that way when I order it. But instead it orders it by "Backlog, New, Blocked, Design, Sign Off, Dev). Which is wrong, it should be ordering by
Backlog, New, Design, Dev, Sign Off, Blocked.

I've scoured their documentaiton and it says the the GUI option for this was added in 6.0, but I don't see it? The only other way i saw was to do it on the backend? Thoughts?

Answer (score 11):

Ordering by status should order the results in the order of status as defined in `Administration > Issues > Statuses`. You can re-order the statuses from that admin page.

The statuses admin page can be found at;

```
https://$JIRA_URL/secure/admin/ViewStatuses.jspa
```